# Material UI: Datagrid: show/hide widget overflows the window size

Tags: material-ui

I am using Material UI Datagrid and have enabled the show/hide column option. The problem with the same is that it overflows the window disrupting my entire layout as shown below:

[image]

I want the popup to be scrollable (by making it fixed-width) and not disrupting my existing layout. Here's my Datagrid code:

```
<div
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
      className={classes.DataGridComponents}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={props.data || rows}
        columns={columns}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
          Footer: GridFooter,
        }}
        className={classes.root}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        scrollbarSize={5}
        pageSize={props.pageSize || 10}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
        density={props.density || 'compact'}
        onSelectionModelChange={updateSelections}
      />
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how to deal with that? Additionally, how can we control the popup flow direction of the same?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering about how to achieve the same, I did it using forcing css from another file and creating a class as shown below:

```
.MuiGridPanelWrapper-root {
  max-height: 25rem;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
  }
}
```

add the above CSS in any css file and import it to your `DataGrid.js` to solve this issue.